# How to create this product in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can Magento handle this?

We are an online retailer of motorcycle parts.

Each part has its own SKU.

One part may have attributes of multiple models and multiple years.

I need to be able to create a configurable product with dropdown menus similar to http://www.motorcycle-superstore.com/14/70/944/28612/ITEM/Vesrah-Racing-Complete-Gasket-Kit.aspx

Below is an extract from the catalogue.

- List item

  - Manufacturer: Honda
  - Model                            Year                    SKU
  - C70K1                            1973                    16-6206
  - CB125S/S1/S2                     73-75                   16-6209
  - CL125S/S1                        73-74                   16-6209
  - CB350G                           1973                    16-6101
  - CB350K2~K5 Super Sport           70-73                   16-6101
  - CL350K2~K5 Scrambler             70-73                   16-6101
  - SL350                            1971                    16-6101
  - CB360G                           73-74                   16-6105
  - CB360T                           75-76                   16-6105

From this table part number 16-6209 will have the following attributes
Manufacturer: Honda
Model: CB125S/S1/S2; CL125S/S1 and Year: 1973,1974,1975

I want to have a configurable product page called Gaskets. On this page the customer will select their Manufacturer, Model and Year.

In the Shopping Cart, the correct SKU as per the table needs to be displayed.

How could I do this?

Comment: you need to create simple product for your parts and add it to a configurable product so that you can maintain everything ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create simple products with make, model and year as attributes. Then the functionality you referred can be achieved by using a search like http://www.onlinecarmats.co.uk/ . All we can do is make the search ajaxed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.  I think my first problem relates to the creating of the simple products.

I have three attributes set up

- bike_manufacturer (dropdown)
- bike_model (multi select)
- bike_year (multi select)

SKU 16-6209 will have the following attributes

- bike_manufacturer: Honda
- bike_model: CB125S/S1/S2
- bike_model: CL125S/S1
- bike_year: 1973
- bike_year: 1974
- bike_year: 1975

When I create the configurable product, only bike_manufacturer will display.

How can I create the simple products, so they have the correct attributes, that will then display in the configurable product?

Answer (score 0):

This is my current attribute structure

- bike_manufacturer (dropdown)

  - Honda
  - Kawasaki
  - Suzuki
  - Triumph
- bike_model_honda (multi-select)

  - C70K1
  - CB125S/S1/S2
  - CL125S/S1
  - CB350G
  - CB350K2~K5 Super Sport
  - CL350K2~K5 Scrambler
  - SL350
  - CB360G
  - CB360T
- bike_year (multiselect)

  - 1970
  - 1971
  - 1972
  - 1973
  - 1974
  - 1975
  - 1976
  - 1977
  - 1978
  - 1979
  - 1980

Answer (score 0):

you have to create  configurable product having super attribute as bike_manufacturer (drop down),bike_model (drop down), bike_year (drop down)after than create associated products for all variations.